# How to validate textbox input if its special characters/symbols or letters in c#?

Tags: c#

The conditions are (a)Check textbox if it is null or empty.(b)Textbox should not accept invalid inputs like symbols and letters. My program is a simple ATM machine

Here are the tips gave to solve the validation problem. The problem is that I don`t know how to validate special characters and symbols I only know how to validate if textbox is empty or not. It should message the user if it input letters or symbols in the textbox if the user click save.

```
double userDefinedVariableName;
if (double.TryParse(TextBox.Text, out userDefinedVariableName)) {//code block}

double parsedNumber;
if (double.TryParse(txtNumber.Text, out parsedNumber)) {//code block}
```

```
private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (withdraw)
            {
                //balance = balance - double.Parse(txtbox_trans.Text);
                //MessageBox.Show("Your balance: " + balance.ToString() + "", "WITHDRAWAL SUCCESSFUL");
                withdraw = false;
                if (balance > double.Parse(txtbox_trans.Text))
                {
                    if (double.Parse(txtbox_trans.Text) < 500)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Minimum withdrawal amount is : 500\nInput a higher amount.", "Amount");
                        withdraw = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        balance = balance - double.Parse(txtbox_trans.Text);
                        MessageBox.Show("Your current balance: " + balance.ToString() + "", "WITHDRAWAL SUCCESSFUL");
                        btn_cb.Enabled = false;
                        btn_dp.Enabled = false;
                        btn_withdraw.Enabled = false;
                        btn_cancel.Enabled = false;
                        btn_save.Enabled = false;
                        btn_new.Enabled = true;
                        txtbox_trans.Enabled = false;
                        txtbox_trans.Text = "CLICK NEW TRANSACTION";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Your current balance is not enough!\nPlease enter a lower amount.", "Not enough balance");
                    withdraw = true;
                }
            }
            else if (deposit)
            {
                deposit = false;
                if (100 > double.Parse(txtbox_trans.Text))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Minimum deposit amount is : 100\nInput a higher amount.", "Amount");
                    deposit = true;
                }
                else if (100000 <= double.Parse(txtbox_trans.Text))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Maximum deposit amount is : 100000\nInput a higher amount.", "Amount");
                    deposit = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    balance = balance + double.Parse(txtbox_trans.Text);
                    MessageBox.Show("Your current balance: " + balance.ToString() + "", "DEPOSIT SUCCESSFUL");
                    deposit = false;
                    btn_cb.Enabled = false;
                    btn_dp.Enabled = false;
                    btn_withdraw.Enabled = false;
                    btn_cancel.Enabled = false;
                    btn_save.Enabled = false;
                    btn_new.Enabled = true;
                    txtbox_trans.Enabled = false;
                    txtbox_trans.Text = "CLICK NEW TRANSACTION";
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: what are the valid inputs you want to accept. just numbers?  do you want to accept `.`, `$`?

Comment: Just numbers like in a simple atm machine

Comment: Is it WinForms? Add tag.

Comment: Try `MaskedTextBox`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regex to check if it's a valid input.  It would look something like this:

```
Regex pattern = new Regex("^[0-9]+$");
if (pattern.IsMatch(txtbox_trans.Text))
{ // the textbox has valid input, do stuff
     int amount = Convert.ToInt32(txtbox_trans.Text);
}
```

This regex just matches numeric values from the start to the end of the string.  So if there's any other characters, it won't match.

You could also probably just use `Int32.TryParse` (which might be easier) something like this:

```
int amount = 0;
if (Int32.TryParse(txtbox_trans.Text, out amount))
{ 
     // valid input, do stuff
}
```

Comment: Side note: `if (int.TryParse(txtbox_trans.Text, out int amount)) {...}` for short